# Question 4.R of Bartle's Elements of Integration.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Can you help me please?

If $f \in M^{+}(X, \mathbf{X})$ and $$\int f d\mu \lt +\infty,$$ then the set $N=\{x \in X: f(x)\gt 0\}$ is $\sigma$-finite (that is, there exists a sequence $(F_n)$ in $\mathbf{X}$ such that $N\subset \cup F_n$ and $\mu (F_n) \lt +\infty$).

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:  Let $F_n = \{x:f(x) \geqslant 1/n\}.$

Can you show  that $F_n$ is measurable and $N \subset \cup F_n?$

Then justify and use

$$\frac1{n} \mu(F_n) \leq \int_{F_n}f d\mu\leq\int_{X}f d\mu.$$